# Improve data comparison performance

Tags: python

How can I improve performance of the following code?

```
self.adverts = set() # Around 11k rows
self.old_adverts= set() # Around 11k rows
self.advs = []

...

# Find modified items
for item in self.new_items:
   for old_item in self.old_items:
       if item.id == old_item.id and item.price != old_item.price:
          self.advs.append(
                    {
                    'delete': old_item,
                    'new': item,
                    'archive': old_item
                    }
          )
```

`Item` class:

```
class Item(Base):
   ...

   id = Column(String(25), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
   price = Column(Numeric(precision=8), nullable=False, primary_key=True)

   # Another multiple additional fields
   ...

   def __eq__(self, other):
       return self.id == other.id

   def __hash__(self):
       return hash(self.id)
```

Above data comparison takes too much time. I don't know how to fast it.

**UPD:**
However, below I have managed to improve the performance of another piece of code:

```
# for item in self.items:
#   if item not in self.old_items:
#       self.insert_items_db.add({'new': item})

# Find absolutely new items
for new_item in self.items- self.old_items:
    self.advs.append({'new': new_item})
```

Objects have predefined `__eq__` and `__hash__` functions:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.id == other.id

def __hash__(self):
    return hash(self.id)
```

Comment: When you find a match you could remove it from both lists if that is a safe assumption.

Comment: What does each item look like? Your comment says 11k rows.. what is in each row? what do items and old items look like? Is it possible that an item.id is repeated or an old_item.id is repeated?

Comment: After a quick look at the code, this looks like a very good candidate for wrapping your data into a database.  You'll get better performance when querying for data items from a db instead of iterating through them in memory.

Comment: @Kronos, good point, I`ll think about it as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully follow your code but you can speed up comparing two lists by using a dictionary. This is O(n) rather than O(n^2) as checking for existance is reduced from O(n) to O(1).

For example. Say you have a bunch of objects with variables id, value, color.

```
for x in list1:       #N operations
    for y in list2:   #N operations
        if x.id == y.id:  #O(1)
            #do stuff
```

instead you could do this:

```
#create two dictionaries where each key is the ID and each value is the
#object, data, other things etc.
dict1 = { x.id:x for x in list1}   
dict2 = { y.id:y for y in list2}
```

And your code now becomes:

```
for x in dict1.keys():     #O(N)
    if x in dict2:         #O(1)
         #Do some stuff
```

which is O(n) time now.

Now if you wish to compare prices it becomes tricky. If we have multiple Id elements *(e.g. there are collisions in the same set)* then we can convert each entry in the dictionary into a list of the objects. This is theoretically still O(N^2) operation but it is a vast improvement over iterating through ALL 11k elements.

Let's assume there are not repeated Ids. The code then becomes:

```
for x in dict1.keys():     #O(N)
    if x in dict2:         #O(1)
        if dict1[x].price != dict2[x].price:  #or any other comparison
             #do stuff
```

If there are repeated Ids then the dictionary structures should instead look like the following:

```
my_dict = {\
    1001: [ obj1, obj2, obj3]\  #where obj1.id == obj2.id == obj3.id
    1002: [obj4, obj5, obj6]\   #where obj4.id == obj5.id == obj6.id
    }
```

with code being adapted to reflect something like the following

```
for x in dict1.keys():     
    if x in dict2:   
        if x in dict2:
            for my_object_type in dict2[x]:     #something about this seems familiar.....
                if x.other_identifier == my_object_type.other_identifer:
                #finally do some stuff!
```

Here's the craziest part of all!

In the above code I've added another for loop. This is again O(N) speed which is why the code has been reduced to O(N^2) again. However if we have another identifier, say "Id2" or "color_of_left_toe" then we can create **ANOTHER DICTIONARY!!**

At this point the structure will have evolved into a dictionary of dictionaries of your object. Quite complex but!! The access time can remain O(1)!

### Why is "in dict" faster?

In the first code example you are iterating through the first list and then again you are iterating through another list.

So for the first element in list1 you iterate through len(list2), or **N**

Because you are looping through this loop for each element in X you are doing this **N** times.

N + N + N + N ............N

\~~~~~~**N times**~~~~~~/

or O(N^2)

now why is dict faster?

A dictionary hashes each element and then stores it based on this hash. This means you don't have to look through a complex binary tree or array to find what you are looking for. Instead you do a bit of O(1) time math and you have the point you need to check right away based on the key that you gave it.

Comment: But I need to compare `price` field as well, not only `id`.

Comment: Easy! As long as we can assume there are not repeated Ids, then you have ANOTHER if block inside the "if x in dic2" which checks the prices of the object. I just posted an update with a better explanation

Comment: Thank you! Very good explanation. Now it becomes clear to me - how and why.

Answer (score 0):

This depends very much on what your "do something" entails.  If this is a simple record update, then forget this `set` implementation and go for a dictionary.  Use the old data to create the old dictionary, keyed on product ID.  Then update it with the new data.

```
catalog =       {self.id: [ <remainder of the row> ] for self in old_data}
catalog.update( {self.id: [ <remainder of the row> ] for self in new_data} )
```